# Asking firebase to resend OTP, it is sending the same OTP and after submitting that throwing error auth/invalid-verification-code OR auth/code-expired

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase auth for OTP service. In the first step, I am entering the mobile number and receive the OTP properly. But as I am testing some edge cases of my logic, I am waiting for 2-3 minutes and asking for resend OTP. Now the problem occurs, as I request for another OTP, I am receiving the previous (same) OTP and after entering that OTP an error is occurring `auth/invalid-verification-code`, sometimes this error is coming and sometimes `auth/code-expired` this error is coming.
The entered OTP is the OTP I last received, but still, the OTP is not getting verified by Firebase.

For resending the OTP I am using the same function which I'd used for receiving the OTP at first, but by providing a different reCAPTCHA container ID. If I enter OTP just after receiving that, it works totally fine but the problem is occurring when I am waiting for 2-3 minutes and ask for resend OTP. Receiving the same OTP but not validating by Firebase.

I am using this code for sending number to firebase and receiving OTP for the first time,

```
  const handleOnChange = async (inputOtp: string) => {
        setOtp(inputOtp);
        if (inputOtp.length === 6) {
            setIsSubmitting(true);
            setOtpError(false);
            try {
                const request = await confirmObj?.confirm(inputOtp);
                const firebaseToken = request?.user?.accessToken;
                if (firebaseToken) {
                    // WHILE SIGNING-UP, 'isUserRegistered' IS FALSE
                    if (!isUserLoggingIn) {
                        const response: any =
                            await checkIsUserRegisteredInBackend({
                                url: "users/isRegistered",
                                headers: {
                                    Authorization: `Bearer ${firebaseToken}`,
                                },
                            }).unwrap();
                        if (response?.data?.isRegistered) {
                            navigate(Paths.WELCOME, { replace: true });
                            openSnackbarFunction(
                                dispatch,
                                "This number has already been registered. Please try logging in.",
                                "error"
                            );
                        } else {
                            dispatch(storeUserFirebaseToken(firebaseToken));
                            navigate(Paths.REGISTRATION, { replace: true });
                            openSnackbarFunction(
                                dispatch,
                                "The OTP has been verified successfully",
                                "success"
                            );
                        }
                        setIsSubmitting(false);
                        setOtpError(false);
                        setIsNumberEntered(false);
                    } else {
                        // WHILE LOGGING-IN, 'isUserRegistered' IS TRUE
                        const reqObject = {
                            url: Urls.AUTH,
                            body: { isSignup: false },
                            headers: {
                                Authorization: `Bearer ${firebaseToken}`,
                            },
                        };
                        try {
                            const response: any = await userSignUpAndLogin(
                                reqObject
                            ).unwrap();
                            if (response?.data?.accessToken) {
                                setUserAuthDetailsInLocalStorage(
                                    "userRefreshToken",
                                    response?.data?.refreshToken
                                );
                                dispatch(
                                    storeUserAccessToken(
                                        response?.data?.accessToken
                                    )
                                );
                                dispatch(storeUserType(response?.data?.role));
                                openSnackbarFunction(
                                    dispatch,
                                    "Login successful",
                                    "success"
                                );
                                setIsNumberEntered(false);
                                navigate("/", { replace: true });
                            }
                        } catch (error: any) {
                            console.log(error);
                            if (error?.status === 400) {
                                openSnackbarFunction(
                                    dispatch,
                                    error?.data?.message.concat(
                                        ", Please try Signing up"
                                    ),
                                    "error"
                                );
                            } else if (error?.status === 422) {
                                openSnackbarFunction(
                                    dispatch,
                                    error?.data?.message,
                                    "error"
                                );
                            } else {
                                openSnackbarFunction(
                                    dispatch,
                                    String(error?.status),
                                    "error"
                                );
                            }
                            navigate(Paths.WELCOME);
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                }
            } catch (error: any) {
                console.log(error, "error message");
                if (error?.code === "auth/invalid-verification-code") {
                    openSnackbarFunction(
                        dispatch,
                        "The OTP entered is incorrect",
                        "error"
                    );
                } else if (error?.code === "auth/invalid-app-credential") {
                    // auth/code-expired
                    openSnackbarFunction(
                        dispatch,
                        "Something went wrong, Please try again",
                        "error"
                    );
                    navigate(Paths.WELCOME);
                } else {
                    openSnackbarFunction(dispatch, String(error), "error");
                }
                setOtpError(true);
                setIsSubmitting(false);
            }
        }
    };
```

Below code for re-sending the OTP,

```
    const handleReSendOtp = async () => {
        setOtp("");
        setOtpError(false);
        setIsSubmitting(true);

        try {
            const response = await setUpRecaptcha(
                another-reCaptcha-container,
                userMobileNo
            );
            if (response?.verificationId) {
                setMinutes(0);
                setSeconds(45);
                openSnackbarFunction(dispatch, "The OTP was resent", "info");
                grecaptcha?.reset();
                setIsSubmitting(false);
            }
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.log(error);
            if (error?.code === "auth/too-many-requests") {
                openSnackbarFunction(dispatch, "Too many attempts", "error");
            } else {
                openSnackbarFunction(dispatch, String(error), "error");
            }
            setIsSubmitting(false);
            navigate(Paths.WELCOME);
        }
    };
```

And below is the code for setting up reCaptcha,

```
export const setUpRecaptcha = async (
    recaptchaContainer: string,
    number: string
) => {
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
        recaptchaContainer,
        {
            size: "invisible",
        },
        auth
    );
    const verificationToken = await window.recaptchaVerifier.verify();
    if (verificationToken) {
        return signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, number, window.recaptchaVerifier);
    }
};
```

This is firebase error which i am getting,

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "SESSION_EXPIRED",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "SESSION_EXPIRED",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code for receiving the OTP?

Comment: Have added it @ColdLogic